# How to simplify equation by change of bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Try to simplify the equation by change of bases (or change of coordinate system) : $2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2 = 1$

1) Find Transition Matrix P from B' to B:

B' = {(2/$\sqrt5$, 1/$\sqrt5$),(-1/$\sqrt5$, 2/$\sqrt5$)

B = {(1,0), (0,1)}

$\begin{bmatrix}
2/\sqrt5 & 
1/\sqrt5 & 
1 & 
0 
\\ 
-1/\sqrt5 & 
2/\sqrt5 & 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ RREF $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 
0 & 
2/\sqrt5 & 
-1/\sqrt5 
\\ 
0 & 
1 & 
1/\sqrt5  & 
2/\sqrt5 
\end{bmatrix}$

P = $\begin{bmatrix} 
2/\sqrt5 & 
-1/\sqrt5 
\\ 
1/\sqrt5  & 
2/\sqrt5 
\end{bmatrix}$

2) Convert a coordinate matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$ relative to the basis $B'$ into the coordinate matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ relative to the basis $B$. Here I choose to make x' and y' = 1.

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 
2/\sqrt5 & 
-1/\sqrt5 
\\ 
1/\sqrt5  & 
2/\sqrt5 
\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}x'=1\\y'=1\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} 
\sqrt2
\\ 
\sqrt1.8
\end{bmatrix}$

3) Plug both $x,y$ found in 2) to the original equation and find a simplified equation in terms of the variables $x', y'$

$2x^2 - 4xy + 5y^2 = 1$  , $x=2$, $y=\sqrt1.8$

$2(2) - 4((\sqrt2)(\sqrt1.8)) + 5(\sqrt1.8)^2) = 1$

5.41 != 0

> Why didn't my equation equal 1 after I plugged in the x, y values that I got from 2)? I don't know what I did wrong...it is supposed to be 1 = 1 isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix $P$ is *not* the inverse of the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac2{\sqrt5}&-\frac1{\sqrt5}\\\frac1{\sqrt5}&\frac2{\sqrt5}\end{bmatrix};$$that would be$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac2{\sqrt5}&\frac1{\sqrt5}\\-\frac1{\sqrt5}&\frac2{\sqrt5}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: damnit. you're right. I am just starting to learn to use Tex and it is hard to keep track of the details.

Comment: I updated my post. Please see the below question